Stripe network error: Payment failed: Error: Network response was not ok
I keep getting Payment failed: Error: Network response was not ok
makePayment CheckoutOrderSummary.jsx:113
when I try to complete a stripe payment order. I can't figure out what is wrong with how I am calling "/api/stripe/create-checkout-session". I believe the issue is on the front end but cannot confirm
Here is my frontend where makePayment starts the stripe api call:


import {
  Flex,
  Heading,
  Stack,
  Text,
  useColorModeValue as mode,
  Badge,
  Box,
  Divider,
  Link,
  Button,
  useDisclosure,
  useToast,
} from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { useEffect, useState, useCallback } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Link as ReactLink, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { createOrder, resetOrder } from "../redux/actions/orderActions";
import { resetCart } from "../redux/actions/cartActions";
import { PhoneIcon, EmailIcon, ChatIcon } from "@chakra-ui/icons";
import CheckoutItem from "./CheckoutItem";
import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js";

const CheckoutOrderSummary = () => {
  //chakra
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const toast = useToast();
  const colorMode = mode("gray.600", "gray.400");

  //redux
  const cartItems = useSelector((state) => state.cart);
  const { cart, subtotal, expressShipping } = cartItems;

  const user = useSelector((state) => state.user);
  const { userInfo } = user;

  const shippingInfo = useSelector((state) => state.order);
  const { error, shippingAddress } = shippingInfo;

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const shipping = useCallback(() => {
    let shippingCost =
      expressShipping === "true" ? 14.99 : subtotal <= 1000 ? 4.99 : 0;
    return parseFloat(shippingCost);
  }, [expressShipping, subtotal]);

  const hst = useCallback(() => {
    const hstValue = ((Number(subtotal) + Number(shipping())) * 0.13).toFixed(
      2
    );
    return parseFloat(hstValue); // Convert hstValue to a number
  }, [expressShipping, subtotal, shipping]);

  const total = useCallback(
    () =>
      Number(
        shipping() === 0
          ? Number(subtotal) + hst()
          : Number(subtotal) + shipping() + hst()
      ).toFixed(2),
    [shipping, subtotal, hst]
  );

  const onPaymentSuccess = async (data) => {
    dispatch(
      createOrder({
        orderItems: cart,
        shippingAddress,
        paymentMethod: data.paymentSource,
        paymentDetails: data,
        shippingPrice: shipping(),
        totalPrice: total(),
        userInfo,
      })
    );

    dispatch(resetOrder());
    dispatch(resetCart());
    navigate("/orderSuccess");
  };

  const onPaymentError = () => {
    toast({
      description:
        "Something went wrong during the payment process. Please try again or make sure that your PayPal account balance is enough for this purchase.",
      status: "error",
      duration: "600000",
      isClosable: true,
    });
  };

  const makePayment = async () => {
    const stripe = await loadStripe(
      REACT_APP_STRIPE_KEY
    );

    try {
      const body = {
        products: cart,
      };
  
      const response = await fetch("/api/stripe/create-checkout-session", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },

        body: JSON.stringify(body),
      });

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("Network response was not ok");
      }

      const session = await response.json();
      if (session.error) {
        throw new Error(session.error);
      }

      const result = await stripe.redirectToCheckout({
        sessionId: session.id,
      });

      if (result.error) {
        throw new Error(result.error.message);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Payment failed:", error);
      toast({
        title: "Payment error",
        description: error.message,
        status: "error",
        duration: 9000,
        isClosable: true,
      });
    }
  };

  return (
    <Stack spacing="8px" rounded="xl" padding="0" width="full">
      <Heading size="md">OrderSummary</Heading>
      {cart.map((item) => (
        <CheckoutItem key={item.id} cartItem={item} />
      ))}
      <Stack spacing="6">
        <Flex justify="space-between">
          <Text fontWeight="medium" color={colorMode}>
            Subtotal
          </Text>
          <Text fontWeight="medium" color={colorMode}>
            ${subtotal.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")}
          </Text>
        </Flex>
        <Flex justify="space-between">
          <Text fontWeight="medium" color={colorMode}>
            Shipping
          </Text>
          <Text fontWeight="medium" color={colorMode}>
            {shipping() === 0 ? (
              <Badge
                rounded="full"
                px="2px"
                fontSize="15px"
                colorScheme="green"
              >
                Free
              </Badge>
            ) : (
              `$${shipping()}`
            )}
          </Text>
        </Flex>
        <Flex justify="space-between">
          <Text fontWeight="medium" color={colorMode} textTransform="upperCase">
            hst
          </Text>
          <Text>
            $
            {hst()
              .toString()
              .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")}
          </Text>
        </Flex>
        <Flex justify="space-between">
          <Text fontSize="lg" fontWeight="semibold">
            Total
          </Text>
          <Text fontSize="xl" fontWeight="extrabold">
            $
            {total()
              .toString()
              .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")}
          </Text>
        </Flex>
      </Stack>
      <Stack>
        <Button as={ReactLink} to="/cart">
          Back to cart
        </Button>
      </Stack>
      <Stack>
        <Button onClick={makePayment}>Confirm</Button>
      </Stack>

      <Box alignItems="center">
        <Text fontSize="sm">Questions or need help?</Text>
        <Flex justifyContent="center">
          <Flex align="center">
            <ChatIcon />
            <Text m="2px">Live Chat</Text>
          </Flex>
          <Flex align="center">
            <PhoneIcon />
            <Text m="2px">Call us</Text>
          </Flex>
          <Flex align="center">
            <EmailIcon />
            <Text m="2px">Email</Text>
          </Flex>
        </Flex>
      </Box>
      <Divider bg={mode("gray.400", "gray.300")} />
      <Flex justifyContent="center" my="6px" fontWeight="semibold">
        <Text>or</Text>
        <Link as={ReactLink} to="/products" ml="1px">
          Continue Shopping
        </Link>
      </Flex>
    </Stack>
  );
};

export default CheckoutOrderSummary;



And here's my stripeRoutes on the backend


import express from "express";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import Stripe from "stripe";

dotenv.config();
const stripe = new Stripe("process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY");
const stripeRoutes = express.Router();

stripeRoutes.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Response from Get Route");
});

stripeRoutes.post("/create-checkout-session", async (req, res) => {
  const { products } = req.body;

  if (!products || !Array.isArray(products) || products.length === 0) {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: "No products provided." });
  }

  try {
    const lineItems = products.map((product) => ({
      price_data: {
        currency: "cad",
        product_data: {
          name: product.name,
          images: product.image ? [product.image] : undefined, // Ensure this is a valid URL if uncommented
        },
        unit_amount: Math.round(product.price * 100), // Ensure price is in cents
      },
      quantity: product.qty,
    }));

    const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
      payment_method_types: ["card"],
      line_items: lineItems,
      mode: "payment",
      success_url: `${req.protocol}://${req.get("host")}/OrderSuccessScreen`, // Use dynamic host
      cancel_url: `${req.protocol}://${req.get("host")}/OrderCancelScreen`, // Use dynamic host
    });

    res.json({ sessionId: session.id });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
  }
});

export default stripeRoutes;



And here's my backend index.js


import dotenv from "dotenv";
import connectToDatabase from "./database.js";
import express from "express";
import path from "path";

//ROUTES
import productRoutes from "./routes/productRoutes.js";
import userRoutes from "./routes/userRoutes.js";
import brandRoutes from "./routes/brandRoutes.js";
import orderRoutes from "./routes/orderRoutes.js";
import stripeRoutes from "./routes/stripeRoutes.js";

dotenv.config();
connectToDatabase();

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(
  express.json({
    limit: "10mb",
  })
);

//names after/api/ must match mongoDB collection names
app.use("/api/products", productRoutes);
app.use("/api/brands", brandRoutes);
app.use("/api/users", userRoutes);
app.use("/api/order", orderRoutes);
app.use("/api/stripe", stripeRoutes);

const __dirname = path.resolve();
app.use("/uploads", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/uploads")));

if (process.env.NODE_ENV == "production") {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/client/build")));

  app.get("*", (req, res) =>
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"))
  );
}

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server runs on port ${port}.`);
});




I was encountering the same issue. I did some debugging and got this error message:
Error creating Stripe portal session: You can’t create a portal session in test mode until you save your customer portal settings in test mode at https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/settings/billing/portal.

Double check that you have setup your portal properly and then try again.
